# I want to see the login page first even any user want access any other page need to redirect to login page in spring security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

> Here is the sample controller. My problem is basically when i am entering the base url it is redirecting to inner page not in the log in page. What i want. What should i do to achieve this.

**Here is the sample controller. My problem is basically when i am entering the base url it is redirecting to inner page not in the log in page. What i want. What should i do to achieve this.**

```
package com.sushovan.security.controller;

import javax.validation.groups.ConvertGroup;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home.jsp";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String loginPage() {
        return "login.jsp";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/logout-success")
    public String logoutPage() {
        return "logout.jsp";
    }
}
```

> Here is the sample Security Configuration class.Mostly all configuration have been done here.

```
package com.sushovan.security.config;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    /**This is for authentication from database**/
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        //provider.setPasswordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());//This is for not use any encryption
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());//This is for BCryptPasswordEncoder
        return provider;
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .usernameParameter("userName").passwordParameter("password")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success").permitAll();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring security filters algorithm works like this ;
is web resource protected ?
is user authenticated ?
is user authorized ?

So if its not authenticated it redirect request to login page, which is what you want.

So you should update your configure method

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .usernameParameter("userName").passwordParameter("password")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success").permitAll();

    }
```

can you please try this and let me know if it works ?

Comment: It works. first my login page is appearing. but i need to do one more thing that is if any use wants to access insider page without accessing login the user should redirect to the login page.

Comment: With this configuration you suppose to not be able to see any page without authentication. When you first run your program can you access any page without authentication ?

Comment: Now a log is appearing that userRepository could not be registered. Why it is showing?

Comment: If i want to expose some of my page then what i need to do?

Comment: If you want to expose pages you need to add  exceptions like this; antMatches(“/pageUrlYouWantToExpose”).permitAll() ... and you can use wildcard here , for example if you antMatches(“/name*”) it will be applied all url start with “name”. You can find more about this if you google Spring Security Filters Configurations

Comment: Ok. Thank you Ali D.A. It really helped me. Thanks